# bar plot in 3d following a given line

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d, bar3d

I want to draw a bar plot in 3d. I know how to do that using the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
nbins = 50
# for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], [30, 20, 10, 0]):
ys = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=10, size=2000)

hist, bins = np.histogram(ys, bins=nbins)
xs = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])/2

ax.bar(xs, hist, zs=30, zdir='y', color='r', ec='r', alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

This will render something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK2If.png

However, my goal is to make the bar plot follows a line that I give as parameter. For example here, the parameter zdir='y' makes the plot have its current direction. Ideally I want to pass a parameter that makes the plot follows a given line for example y=2x+1.

Could someone help arrive at the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that is by using `Poly3DCollection`: the idea is to compute the coordinates and orientation of each bar, then add it to the plot.

The position and orientation of each bar can be computed starting from a rectangle in 3D space and applying the appropriate transformation matrix.

If you are going to change the `curve`, you will also need to change the bar `width`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

################
# Generates data
################
nbins = 50
ys = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=10, size=2000)
hist, bins = np.histogram(ys, bins=nbins)
xs = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])/2

#################################################
# Create a single bar and a transformation matrix
#################################################

# rectangle of width=height=1, centered at x,y=0
# covering the z range [0, height]
rect = np.array([
    [-0.5, 0, 0, 1],
    [0.5, 0, 0, 1],
    [0.5, 0, 1, 1],
    [-0.5, 0, 1, 1],
])
def translate(x, y, z):
    d = np.eye(4, dtype=float)
    d[:, -1] = [x, y, z, 1]
    return d
def scale(sx, sy, sz):
    d = np.eye(4, dtype=float)
    d[np.diag_indices(4)] = [sx, sy, sz, 1]
    return d
def rotate(t):
    d = np.eye(4, dtype=float)
    d[:2, :2] = np.array([
    [np.cos(t), -np.sin(t)],
    [np.sin(t), np.cos(t)]])
    return d
def transformation_matrix(t, x, y, z, w, h):
    return translate(x, y, z) @ rotate(t) @ scale(w, 1, h)
def apply_transform(t, x, y, z, w, h):
    """Apply the transformation matrix to the rectangle"""
    verts = transformation_matrix(t, x, y, z, w, h) @ rect.T
    return verts.T

#################
# Create the plot
#################
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

curve = lambda x: 2 * x + 1
# curve = lambda x: np.sin(0.05 * x)

xstep = abs(xs[0] - xs[1])
# NOTE: chose an appropriate bar width
width = xstep * 1.5

ys = curve(xs)
# previous bar coordinates
xp = np.roll(xs, 1)
yp = np.roll(ys, 1)
xp[0] = xs[0] - xstep
yp[0] = curve(xp[0])
# compute the orientation of the bars
theta = np.arctan2((ys - yp), (xs - xp))

# customize the appearance of the bar
facecolor = "tab:red"
edgecolor = "k"
linewidth = 0
# loop to add each bar
for x, y, t, h in zip(xs, ys, theta, hist):
    verts_matrix = apply_transform(t, x, y, 0, width, h)
    x, y, z = verts_matrix[:, 0], verts_matrix[:, 1], verts_matrix[:, 2]
    verts = [list(zip(x, y, z))]
    c = Poly3DCollection(verts, facecolor=facecolor, edgecolor=edgecolor, linewidth=linewidth)
    ax.add_collection3d(c)

# eventually show a legend
ax.legend([Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, facecolor=facecolor, edgecolor=edgecolor, linewidth=linewidth)], ["Bar Plot"])
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

ax.set_xlim(xs.min(), xs.max())
ax.set_ylim(ys.min(), ys.max())
ax.set_zlim(0, 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT** to explain what is going on:

Consider a generic rectangle with 4 vertices: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left. For simplicity, let's fix width=height=1. Then we consider a reference system x,y,z and we draw this rectangle. The coordinates of vertices are: bottom left (-0.5, 0, 0), bottom right (0.5, 0, 0), top right (0.5, 0, 1) and top left (-0.5, 0, 1). Note that this rectangle is centered around the zero in the x direction. If we move it to x=2, then it will be centered at that location. You can see the above coordinates in `rect`: why does this variable has a fourth column filled with ones? That's a mathematical trick to be able to apply a translation matrix to the vertices.

Let's talk about [transformation matrices (wikipedia has a nice page about it)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix). Consider again our generic rectangle: we can scale it, rotate it and translate it to get a new rectangle in the position and orientation we want.

So, the code above defines a function for each transformation, `translate, scale, rotate`. Turns out that we can multiply together multiple transformation matrices to get an overall transformation: that's what `transformation_matrix` does, it combines the aforementioned transformations into a single matrix.

Finally, I used `apply_transform` to apply the transformation matrix to the generic rectangle: this will compute the coordinates of the vertices of the new rectangle, in the specified position/orientation with the specified size (width, height).

Comment: "The position and orientation of each bar can be computed starting from a rectangle in 3D space and applying the appropriate transformation matrix." I can't understand this part as well as the code related to it. Could you explain more please?

Comment: Ok, I have edited the answer to better explain what's going on.

Comment: What do you mean with "normalize"?

Comment: The integral under the surface of the histogram is one

Comment: The z axis here is between 0 and 100. with other data it can be between 0 and 500 or any other number. I want to make it between 0 and 1

Comment: You might need to normalize `hist`, like this: `hist = hist / hist.max()`

Comment: Yeah that's true. I still need help with one final point. I need to translate histogram over the line on which it is drawn. More precisely, I want to be able to give coordinates for each bin or maybe for for one of the bins so that the histogram is positioned on the line accordingly

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are trying to do....

Comment: So in your code there is "curve" which is a function that represents the equation of a line. Using the transformations, the barplot will be on that line we defined in function curve. So what I want to do is to position my barplot on a specific position on that line.

Comment: You can apply an offset to `xs`.

Comment: When I did that, the barplot is no longer on the line. I mean it is translated but not on the direction of the line